# Net Core 3.1 Razor Pages Multiple Nested Many to Many queries with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, many-to-many, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using .NET Core 3.1, which has some differences to pre .NET Core 3.0 around Linq queries from what I can gather: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client.
There seems to be a lot of information out there for earlier versions of .Net core that don't quite work for me.
All join tables and entities should be configured correctly for automatic creation, so I won't add them all unless someone needs to see them.
In light of that link I also need to be careful that I don't download the entire notes database, which could be millions of lines eventually. Some advice on tracking or notracking, firstordefaultasync etc might be helpful to if it makes a difference.
@Rena helped me with this earlier to get this example working for a single many to many query, thanks heaps Rena:

```
public async Task<List<Note>> GetAllNotesForNoteTypeAsync(string notetype)
        {
            var noteData = await context.Note
                    .Include(n => n.NoteNoteTypeJoins)
                        .ThenInclude(t => t.NoteType)
                    .ToListAsync();
            var noteDataWithTypes = noteData.Where(i => i.NoteNoteTypeJoins.Any(x => x.NoteType.Type.ToString() == notetype))
                    .ToList();
            return noteDataWithTypes;
        }
```

I have another query I need, which goes one level deeper. These two attempts below obviously don't work but they explain what I am trying to do, trying to filter notes by notetype group text, which is four tables removed via two many to many relationships:

```
public async Task<List<Note>> GetAllNotesForNoteTypeGroupAsync(string notetypegroup)
{
      var noteData = await context.Note
                .Include(n => n.NoteNoteTypeJoins)
                        .ThenInclude(t => t.NoteType)
                            .ThenInclude(gt => gt.NoteTypeNoteTypeGroupJoins)
                                .ThenInclude(g => g.NoteTypeGroup)
                    .Where(g => g.NoteTypeGroup.Group == notetypegroup)
                    .ToListAsync();

            return noteData;
        }
```

or:

```
public async Task<List<Note>> GetAllNotesForNoteTypeGroupAsync(string notetypegroup)
{
    var noteData = await context.Note
            .Select(note => new
            {
                mytypejoin = note.NoteNoteTypeJoins
                .Select(notetypejoin => new
                {
                    mynotetype = notetypejoin.NoteType
                    .Select(notetype => new
                    {
                        mynotetype = notetype.NoteTypeNoteTypeGroupJoins
                        .Select(notetypegroupjoins => new
                        {
                            mytypegroup = notetypegroupjoins
                                .Where(i => i.NoteTypeNoteTypeGroupJoins
                                    .Any(x => x.NoteTypeGroup.Group.ToString() == notetypegroup)
                        }),
                    }),
                }),
            });


    return noteData;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm fairly new to this, Thank you!

Here is the answer compliments of Chris:

```
var noteData = await context.Note.Where(n =>
                n.NoteNoteTypeJoins.Any(ntj =>
                    ntj.NoteType.NoteTypeNoteTypeGroupJoins.Any(ntg => ntg.NoteTypeGroup.Group == notetypegroup)))
                .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use `Any` recursively to dig into the lower relationships, but it does get ugly.

```
var noteData = await context.Note.Where(n =>
    n.NoteTypeJoins.Any(ntj =>
        ntj.NoteType.Any(nt =>
            nt.NoteTypeNoteTypeGroupJoins.Any(ntntgj =>
                ntntgj.NoteTypeGroup.Group == notetypegroup)))))
    .ToListAsync();
```

You don't need all the `Include` and `ThenInlude`, as EF will automatically issue the necessary joins in order to make the query in the first place, since it includes all these relationships.

It's also important to note (and will become more problematic with deeper level queries like this), that it's not going to just return `NoteType`s, for example, that are in this group. It's going to return `Note`s (since that's the base entity you're querying) that have any `NoteType`s in this group, with *all* the related `NoteType`s, whether they're in the group or not. You just won't have notes where there are zero associated note types in this group.

If you're looking to filter the actual relationships, you'll have to explicitly load. See:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#querying-related-entities

Comment: Brilliant Chris, thanks heaps, I'm off and running. Got exactly the records I was looking for, all notes with note types in the note type group. Will add the answer to my question. It was a little shorter than that in the end once intellisense had a look at it: var noteData = await context.Note.Where(n =>
                n.NoteNoteTypeJoins.Any(ntj =>
                    ntj.NoteType.NoteTypeNoteTypeGroupJoins.Any(ntg => ntg.NoteTypeGroup.Group == notetypegroup)))
                .ToListAsync();